# Как получить из статической строки динамические цифры

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

JS

```
$http
    .jsonp('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www.nbrb.by/RSS/?p=RatesDaily&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.ByBankFeed = data.data.responseData.feed.entries[0].contentSnippet;             
    });
```

HTML

```
{{ByBankFeed}}
```

Получаем

```
Евро 23 002,00 Доллар США 20 206,00 Российский рубль 294,21
```

Каким способ мне получить курс США, а именно **20206**, учитывая, что в данной строке будут меняться цифры, а слова статичны. Далее полученный результат планируется применять для формулы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если есть уверенность, что формат строки не изменится, можно регулярными выражениями распарсить:

```
$http
.jsonp('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www.nbrb.by/RSS/?p=RatesDaily&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
.then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    var str, usd;
    str = data.data.responseData.feed.entries[0].contentSnippet;
    usd = str.match(/.+Доллар США (.+) Российский рубль.*/)[1].replace(/[\s,]/g, '') / 100;
    $log.log(usd);
});
```

(не помешает проверка результата str.match, на случай некорректной исходной строки)

Comment: а как мне передать значения usd в контроллер, только вне $http.jsonp функции? Т.к. ng-init="inputInit($parent.$index, $index, $parent.$last, datafields.cost*ByBankUSD)" не видит $scope.ByBankUSD

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, это не самый хороший способ - парсить строки для получения числа, что бы потом использовать его в формуле.

Но если надо, можно использовать [регулярные выражения](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions-javascript):

Пример.

```js
var a = "Евро 23 002,00 Доллар США 20 206,00 Российский рубль 294,21";
var r = /Доллар США ([0-9 ]*(,[0-9])*)/i;
var res = a.match(r);
console.log(res[1]);
```

### Update

Если Вы хотите получить список курс США к различным валютам, лучше использовать готовые `API`, чем парсить строчку.

Например:

- Курсы от [НАЦИОНАЛЬНЫЙ БАНК РЕСПУБЛИКИ БЕЛАРУСЬ](http://www.nbrb.by/statistics/Rates/XML). Запрос http://www.nbrb.by/Services/XmlExRates.aspx?ondate=01/31/2016.
- Курсы от [Центральный Банк РФ](http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/Root.asp?PrtId=SXML). Запрос http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=02/03/2016